# Adding custom post title to wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

Excuse my rookieness – this might be a very simple thing to solve for someone with more experience. I tried searching the forum but did not find a fitting solution.

I am trying to make my Wordpress menu add the custom title to a current menu item on a specific post type when that page is active, what would be the best way to do so?

```
Menu <--- Original menu item<br>
Menu: Addition <--- When on the custom post type titled "Addition"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are here to help, but you need to show that you have at least attempted to solve the problem yourself. Please show us what you've tried / provide some code :)

Comment: Edited the question to separate literature from code/UI.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with finding the code in the template ( theme ) where menu is being rendered. You need to look for function that renders navigation menu `wp_nav_menu()`:https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Depending on how complicated solution you want to choose to pick for checking the post type - I would suggest simple `if()` statement.

To check post type you can use `get_post_type()`:https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/

If post type is "Addition" pass argument to `wp_nav_menu()` to use custom menu prepare for that post type.